# Regression test with random IDs

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to create regression tests, but every version upgrade generate new random IDs. Consequently in the new version fails all test cases. For example:

Version 1.1

```
driver.findElement(By.id("baseInputItems:0:j_idt2468_label")).click();
```

Version 1.2

```
driver.findElement(By.id("baseInputItems:0:j_idt875_label")).click();
```

How can I solve this problem in Selenium WebDriver with Java? Will be grateful for any help.

Two elements from my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;componentIndicators:0:j_idt2989:text_bldata&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,f:&quot;newApplicationForm&quot;,p:&quot;componentIndicators:0:j_idt2989:text_bldata&quot;,ps:true});" size="10" maxlength="100" value="1" name="componentIndicators:0:j_idt2989:text_bldata" id="componentIndicators:0:j_idt2989:text_bldata" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
<input type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="text-align:left;" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:text_blyear&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,f:&quot;newApplicationForm&quot;,p:&quot;componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:text_blyear&quot;,ps:true});" size="10" maxlength="10" value="1" name="componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:text_blyear" id="componentIndicators:1:j_idt2989:text_blyear" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
```

Comment: Assign ids and they will not be generated

Comment: pls post your html code, then there might be a solution

Comment: maybe with an XPath, but we need to see your DOM to help you =)

Comment: Posted my HTML code, but there is a lot of buttons and text boxes on a web page.

Comment: Is there any other element with that attribute: class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" ?

Comment: the worst case is use the longest unique xpath selector

Comment: @Mahsum Akbas: Yes, cicra 15.

Comment: can you pls post some more of these elements -> are there more elements that have "baseInputItems" in there id? if yes, pls post some of them too

Comment: I can't use the longest unique xpath selector, because every version upgrade generate new random IDs and all j_idt* part will change.

Comment: Edited my HTML code.

Comment: I have similar problem. There are many solutions. If your DOM structure is not changed, select element by type or attribute or class with index number. Please, tell which element you want to select? input? span?

Comment: i would like to use sendKeys() method: driver.findElement(By.id("componentIndicators:0:j_idt2859:text_bldata")).sendKeys(array[0]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your input elements can be identified via this part of there id:

```
componentIndicators:0:
componentIndicators:1:
```

Because on of your mentioned input elements has the "0", the other the "1"

If this is really the case, you can then search via xpath:

```
WebElement elementWithIdZero = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'componentIndicators:0:')]"));
WebElement elementWithIdOne = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'componentIndicators:1:')]"));
```

Comment: And what can i do in this case:
driver.findElement(By.id("f1:resultList:j_idt28:filter")).sendKeys("MD3");
driver.findElement(By.id("f1:resultList:j_idt29:filter")).sendKeys("A");
driver.findElement(By.id("f1:resultList:j_idt30:filter")).sendKeys("11");

Comment: @Milky do all 3 findElement calls find different elements on your webpage? if yes the ids are poorly designed -> then we would need more information about the elements themselves and the elements which surround them -> from these ids alone you cannot find "the" element your are searching for

Comment: <th id="f1:resultList:j_idt28" class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-column ui-filter-column" role="columnheader" tabindex="0">
<span class="ui-column-title">Project Code</span>
<span class="ui-sortable-column-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
<input id="f1:resultList:j_idt28:filter" class="ui-column-filter ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" value="" name="f1:resultList:j_idt28:filter" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
</th>

Comment: They differ only in the random identifier and the span part, and they are on the same page.

Comment: @Milky yes! but the input element is a child of a th-element, that for example has "tabindex="0" -> maybe the other th-elements have another tabindex -> then you can find them via xpath! -> maybe post another question with a bit more of the html strucutre you posted here as a comment, I will explain then to you how you can approach such a difficult search